# Singleton between many classes?

Tags: java, singleton

I've got quite disturbing problem with singleton in my project.
I created a class called Singleton (how creative) with a variable String name;

Then I created another class called Player where I take a name of user.

And main class where I want to save the data kept in Singleton.

The problem is, it saves name of the user only if I take it in main class..it seems not to work in other classes.

What is the reason ? How to fix it?
Thanks for any advice :)

Here's my singleton class:

```
private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName( ) {
        return 
        this.name;
    }

    private static Singleton instance = null;
    protected Singleton() {
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) 
        {
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

This is a class where I take a name of a user:

```
    public class NewMain {

        public NewMain() {
            String u_name="agrfd";
            Singleton.getInstance().setName(u_name); 
        }
    }
```

And here is main class where I would like to save all data from Singleton (here I just try to print it to make sure it works):

```
public class NewMain1 {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Singleton singleton = new Singleton();
    System.out.println(singleton.getInstance().getName());


}
}
```

Comment: post some minimal example, otherwise we can only guess. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Just guessing without any code ... but are you sure that all different classes are really using the **same** singleton object?!

Comment: 1. You shouldnt create (and even be able to) create Singleton in NewMain1 class. 2. The code in main doesn't execute code in NewMain automacically. Do call that somewhere? Otherwise you only call your getter

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using different instances of Singleton design object. Just use Singleton pattern.

Exemplary implementation:

```
public class ClassicSingleton {
   private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;
   protected ClassicSingleton() {
      // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
   }
   public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new ClassicSingleton();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

[Source](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html)

Your usage should be:

```
public class NewMain1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NewMain(); // execute constructor with setter on creation first
        System.out.println(Singleton.getInstance().getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think my singleton class is alright. But I am sure I do something wrong with using this in other classes. Could you show me and example how it should look like in my code above ?

Comment: Take a look now. You haven't created object of NewMain class at all so your setter was never executed.

Comment: Thank you so much damienix. All works now and I understand the mistake. Many kisses ! +1

Comment: damienix - miło widzieć,że polacy też się udzielają ;)